# How can I test for Three Conditions, and then delete an entire row if all conditions are TRUE?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a sheet that I want to check the language in Column R for <> ‘Cash’; if ‘Cash’ do skip to the next row.  If Column R <> ‘Cash’, check Column A for duplicate ID (there may or may not be duplicates).  If duplicates are found, I want to check Column K for positive/negative values, like 100000 & -100000, then delete the entire row where the negative value appears in Column K.  How can I do that?

Following the roles described above, row 6 would be deleted in the image below.

[image]

I could use VBA in Excel, or SQL/VBA in Access.

Comment: Please show an attempt. You can just evaluate multiple comparisons using the `AND` statement (if you want 3 to be True, you can just use `Test1 AND Test2 AND Test3`, both in SQL, VBA and expressions). In a worksheet, you can use `AND(Test1, Test2, Test3)`

Comment: It is easy to write, since this is involved with deleting a row you should write a VBA code, but if you want to do this only once, you can write formulas that can pick the rows that should be deleted and you can manually delete them, but still VBA will be more decent. I am surprised that you already know the rules on the forum and you have posted such a question with no codes!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well.

```
Sub TryMe()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1

For i = 2 To 13
For j = 2 To 13

If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = ws.Range("A" & j).Value Then
    If ws.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 10).Value = -(ws.Range("A" & j).Offset(0, 10).Value) Then
        If ws.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 17).Value <> "Cash" Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End If
    Exit For
End If

Next j
Next i

End Sub
```